# SQL Server 2014 Backups not inheriting NTFS permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ntfs, sql-server-2014

I am running a script I run on all my SQL servers however on this specific server I have run into the problem where the script fails to make a copy of the DB backups in an external location because the script gets access denied on the newly created local database backups.

For whatever reason, the backups do no inherit NTFS permissions and use the permissions associated with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the login account that is running the script?  You have to make sure that the login running the script, whether it is SQL Agent account or some other account has write permissions on the folder where you are copying the files to.

Comment: That was the actual problem, I forgot to delete this question. Thanks though!